# How to add functionality to classes

Tags: asp.net, oop, c#-3.0

I have a bunch of classes that I would like to be able to 'bolt-on' some functionality.

The functionality involves implementing a property and being able to perform an action that makes use of that property and other members unique to each class. It feels like an interface and an abstract class mixed together. I cannot use the abstract class approach because these classes already are sub-classes of many different classes. I can use an interface, but where do I put the code? I am tired of writing it over and over in each class.

Here's an instance of this problem: I am working in C#, ASP.NET, web forms. The classes I would like to 'bolt-on' to are custom controls (.ascx, .cs) that inherit from many different web controls. The functionality has to do with registering some script on the page after they have created their child controls.

Any insight is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: You should have a Look at PostSharp and Learn about Aspect Oriented Programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern). Create a new object that implements the functionality you are trying to "bolt on." Create an interface that represents the API of this new object. Then implement the interface on your objects:

```
public class MyCompositeObject: Base, IBoltOn
{
    protected IBoltOn BoltOn = new BoltOn();

    # region IBoltOn members
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        BoltOn.SomeMethod();
    }
    public sometype SomeProperty {
        get {
           return BoltOn.SomeProperty;
        }
        set {
            BoltOn.SomeProperty=value;
        }
    }
    # endregion
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like an elegant solution to the problem.

Comment: It's a pattern that is in some ways counterintuitive because you feel like you end up writing a lot of do-nothing properties. And you do, but once you get over that, you learn to love the bomb. Don't be tempted to expose the BoltOn object directly and use its methods like `MyCompositeObjectInstance.BoltOn.SomeProperty..` -- that breaks the usefulness of the interface and the API.

Answer (score 1):

[Extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) possibly provide what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [visitor pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternVisitor.aspx) might help with this. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern):

> A practical result of this separation is the ability to add new operations to existing object structures without modifying those structures.

You're running into a common problem with convoluted inheritance chains, they can be extremely difficult to modify.